# Adjective Noun vs. Adjective in a formal brand name

Tags: adjetivos, nombres-propios

I'm stylizing a brand name and while one sounds better, I don't quite know if it'd be acceptable in a traditional sense.

The name I like is Tequila Viernes. This should be Friday Tequila, which is what I want. I don't understand whether Viernes classifies as an adjective noun or an adjective. The example I saw on here was "gato grande" or "big cat". Big and Friday to me are essentially the same, nebulous ideas without a physical form, but one is formal.

Would that make my usage justifiable or would native speakers have a problem with it? Tequila de Viernes does not flow as well as Tequila Viernes, so for a brand it's a tough line to walk.

Answer (score 1):

### Tequila Viernes

should work Ok for a brand.

I think so mainly because branding —in practice— doesn't have to correspond to grammar rules. At least it does not work like that, and there are tons of examples where there is leeway from the rules.

That would be acceptable when you want to convey the idea of

> Viernes de tequila
> or 
> Tequila de viernes

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that viernes is a noun. Brand names in Spanish can take the form of the name of the article (in your case tequila) followed by or preceded by a noun in apposition to it. I am not a tequila expert but an internet search reveals other tequila examples although I cannot always be sure that the name is the one used in the Spanish-speaking world.